# Extracting text from class using beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#StringFormatInvalid">
<i class="material-icons error-icon">error</i>Invalid format string (1)</a>
```

All of the items of interests are with the tag , but I want to extract the text from that tag. How should I go on about this?

Comment: Based on your example above, what would be the resulting text after extraction?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know if you want the text inside the `<i>` tag or all the text inside the `<a>` tag.

Anyway, here is a snippet to find the both:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = """<a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#StringFormatInvalid">
<i class="material-icons error-icon">error</i>Invalid format string (1)</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

a = soup.find('a', {'class': 'mdl-navigation__link'})
i = soup.find('i', {'class': 'material-icons error-icon'})

print('a text = ', a.get_text())
print('i text = ', i.get_text())
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
a text =  
errorInvalid format string (1)

i text =  error
```